# how to set names for each attachment images in iOS

Tags: ios, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I want to send an email within my iOS application. That mail should include 2 images as attachments. And also name of each image should be appeared after an each emage. But I don't know how to set this name with the attachments. I used `MFMailComposeViewController`. This is not the email body text. Can any one help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The last parameter of the `MFMailComposeViewController addAttachmentData:mimeType:fileName:` method is the name you give to the attachment. It can be anything you want but it should be a sensible name such as `image1.png` or whatever.

Comment: I gave this  [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpg" fileName:@"Nebulizer"]; but it doesn't display in anywhere of the view controller.

Comment: That should work though the mimeType should be `image/jpeg`. What happens when you run this on a device and actually send the email? Is the received email showing the proper attachment names?

Comment: attachments are displayed.. but not the attachment names

Comment: Are the images shown in the email or just as an attachment icon? Depending on the mail client, the image attachments may appear in the mail as the actual images. This is a function of the receiver's email client.

Comment: attached images are displayed both in email and the device,, but not the attachment name. they displays as actual image,,,